# How do I create a new column that is the subtraction of two rows in R?

Tags: sql, database, r

My table looks something like this:

```
Date    Sample_Total    Actual
1/1         2             3
1/2         4             5
1/3         6             7
```

What I'd like to do is add a new column that shows the change in the sample from the previous day, i.e.

```
Date    Sample_Total    Actual   Change
1/1         2             3         -
1/2         4             5         2 
1/3         6             7         2
```

I do realize that this is a simple question, but I've omitted my real tables/connections and such. I'm sure there's an easy way to do this, just not really sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `diff`.

Take `dat` to be your data object.  Since you have all numeric columns to begin with (except Date), it's best to make sure the new column will also be numeric.  So instead of using a `-` mark, `NA` (or zero) is more appropriate.

```
> dat$Change <- with(dat, c(NA, diff(Actual)))
> dat
#   Date Sample_Total Actual Change
# 1  1/1            2      3     NA
# 2  1/2            4      5      2
# 3  1/3            6      7      2
```

You can also use `within`, which can come in handy because it returns the data with any changes made to it.  But this is slower than the above method.

```
> within(dat, { Change <- c(NA diff(Actual)) })
#   Date Sample_Total Actual Change
# 1  1/1            2      3     NA
# 2  1/2            4      5      2
# 3  1/3            6      7      2
```

Comment: Using "-" would be really odd. If data looks like it's numeric/integer, it should be stored as numeric/integer.

Comment: @thelatemail - after thinking about it, I made an edit